# Is this still fuzzy logic?

Tags: fuzzy-logic

I have a question about how to implement fuzzy logic in my application, but it's better to explain with a classic example.
If I use fuzzy logic to control the steering of a car, with the range of the output as : -1 (left), 0 (ahead) and +1 (right), I can directly use the number from the output to control the car. 
In the case I'm using fuzzy logic to control the behaviour, represented with a set of defined actions, so no numbers involved, I would have for example : -1 (evil), 0 (neutral), +1 (good). I can get an output that can range from -1 to 1, so if I get 0,385 as output, how do I translate it to the set of actions?
I was thinking of doing something like :

```
 if output < -0.5

      evilActions()

 if output > -0.5 && output < 0.5

      neutralActions()

 if output > 0.5

      goodActions()
```

or I was also thinking of cheking the values of the membership functions and take the highest value as the output, something like :

result.value = 0

```
 foreach (membershipFunctions mf)

      if (mf.value > result.value)

           result = mf

 if (result.label == "good")

      goodActions()

 if (result.label == "neutral")

      neutralActions()

 if (result.label == "evil")

      evilActions()
```

The problem here is that I'm not sure anymore if this can be still considered fuzzy logic at all.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I totaly understand your confusion, i'm in the same boat as you. Would love someone to shred some light on this.